# How to fit a longitudinal model with binary outcomes

Tags: mixed-model, binomial-distribution, panel-data, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I'd like to fit a **longitudinal model** for where *multiple subjects experience binary outcomes over time*. To accomplish that, I'd like to use an additive random effect for each subject and an autoregressive error process to model the temporal stability in the "success probability."

To illustrate, I'm simulating data from the following model:

$\text{logit}(\mu_{it}) =  \alpha_i + \beta x_i + \epsilon_{it}$

where

$\alpha_i \sim \text{N}(0, \sigma_{\alpha}^2), \quad \epsilon_{it} \sim \rho \, \epsilon_{i, t-1} + \nu_t, \quad \nu_t \sim \text{N}(0, \sigma_{\nu}^2)$

and we observe:

$Y_{it} \sim \text{Bernoulli}(\mu_{it}),$

for subjects $i = 1, \ldots, N$ and time periods $t = 1, \ldots, T$.

It's kind of a lame longitudinal model because there aren't any fixed growth terms (e.g., a function of time), but I think it will suffice for the purposes of this discussion.

The lme4 package in R does a really nice job with everything in this problem except for the temporal stability issue. So I went to **nlme**, but I don't think it ever work, at least the way I'm trying to use it. I'd like to know what went wrong, and any strategies to make this a reality.

*Data Generating Process*

```
N <- 500
n <- 15
ar = 0.8
dat.list <- list()
ids.list <- list()
fixed.list <- list()
ran.effs <- .75 * rnorm(N)
x <- rnorm(N)
for (i in 1:N) {
  lin.pred <- 0 + ran.effs[i] + .7 * x[i] + arima.sim(n = n, list(ar = ar, sd = .5))
  dat.list[[i]] <- as.numeric(runif(n) <= plogis(lin.pred))
  ids.list[[i]] <- rep(i, n)
  fixed.list[[i]] <- rep(x[i], n)
}

longit.df <- data.frame(id = unlist(ids.list),
                        x = unlist(fixed.list),
                        y = unlist(dat.list))
```

*Model Fitting* (tons of errors)

```
library(nlme)
my.nlme <- lme(y ~ x, data = longit.df,
               random = ~ 1 | id,
               weight = varPower(form = ~ fitted(.)*(1-fitted(.)), fixed = 1),
               cor = corAR1(0.6, form = ~ 1 | id))
```

Comment: Ben, your question would be even better if you included some equations of the model(s) you'd like to fit before you get to a coding attempt.